# Python dict changes ordering - how get 1st occurence?

Tags: python, loops, sorting, dictionary

I am trying for 2 hours to get the first occurrence of a key-value pair that has a specific value. (tuples are keys, values are integers).

Why is this relevant ? The dict is sorted by the keys.

I can pprint() the dict and I see the first occurence is the one I want - BUT iterating over the dict and putting out the first occurence using itemgetter outputs the WRONG tuple.

The runnable code is here: https://repl.it/repls/WatchfulStridentLight
The lines that are relevant are 54 to 86 (mind the large debug sections)

```
pprint([k for k,v in allsmall.items() if v>=maxb]) #HERE, the 2nd tuple IS WHAT I WANT, the correct value
```

This would be my go-to solution to get that first occurence from pprint:

```
print(max(allsmall.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]) #almost minimum
```

*But it gets the 2nd occurence* ?!

This completely breaks the ordering:

```
print(max(allsmall.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))[0])
```

Expected: First occurrence can be accessed because pprint() prints it correctly

Actual: I get second occurence....

Comment: Prior to Python 3.6 python dictionaries are *inherently unordered* (indeed, this isn't guaranteed until Python 3.7). Even if this is the case, if you are relying on the order of a dictionary, this means you probably shouldn't be using a dictionary, but some other data-structure. Note, I wouldn't trust the output of `pprint` for this sort of thing

Comment: The key was (as is well documented and lamented here on stackoverflow) that the ordereddict needs to be filled with an array of tuples, which should be sorted.

Comment: it can be filled with any ordered iterable of key value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Use `OrderedDict`. It preserves insertion order so you should get the first occurrence.

Comment: The key was (as is well documented and lamented here on stackoverflow) that the ordereddict needs to be filled with an array of tuples, which should be sorted.